# How to jump to the next line when defining a function in Python?

Tags: python, function, terminal

I am using a Mac terminal to learn Python basics at the moment and I can't figure out how to write a new line when defining a function, because whenever I hit "Enter", it just throws an error.

```
        >>> def f():
        ... a = 10
          File "<stdin>", line 2
            a = 10
            ^
        IndentationError: expected an indented block after function definition on line 1
        >>>
```

Comment: Python function bodies need to be indented. Hitting the tab key once should be sufficient.

Comment: [The Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html#the-python-tutorial) can help get you through the basics.

Comment: Makes sense now, but at the beginning, i felt helpless with such a silly thing :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indentation indicates where blocks begin and end.  Everything inside a function definition is indented:

```
>>> def f():
...     a = 10
...     print(a)
...
>>> f()
10
```

The first line that is *not* indented indicates the function is over.